# Shorten a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to write a query that would calculate number of tickets purchased consisting only of movie genre of that type. At the end, I have to return movie genre and number of tickets bought for that genre. I have written a query but I was wondering if it can be made shorter and more compact?

Following is the database scheme:

```
movies(movieId, movieGenre, moviePrice)
tickets(ticketId, ticketDate, customerId)
details(ticketId, movieId, numOfTickets)
```

Here is my query:

```
select m.genre, count(*)
from(select t.ticketId, m.genre
     from(select d.ticketId
          from(select m.genre, t.ticketId
               from tickets t join details d on t.ticketId = 
                 d.ticketId join movies m on d.movieId = m.movieId
               group by m.genre, t.ticketId) d
          group by d.ticketId
          having count(*) = 1) as t join details d on t.ticketId = 
          d.ticketId join movies m on d.movieId = m.movieId
     group by t.ticketId, m.genre) m
group by m.genre;
```

This runs on a database so I am only able to post sample output:

```
comedy    29821
action    27857
rom-com   19663
```

Comment: Isn't this just supposed to be a `SUM(numOfTickets)` with a `GROUP BY movieGenre` over a double join? Don't see the need for `COUNT` and subqueries.

Comment: I haven't tried doing that. Would you mind showing what it would look like as a query? Specifically what you mean by double join in this case? @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: From the top of my head: `SELECT m.movieGenre, SUM(d.numOfTickets) FROM details d LEFT JOIN tickets t ON d.ticketId = t.ticketId LEFT JOIN movies m ON d.movieId = m.movieId GROUP BY m.movieGenre` Haven't done SQL in a while so your mileage may vary...

Comment: I tried it but I get a table with millions of entries for each genre so I'm assuming its taking in duplicates as well. Any way to get around that using the query you mentioned?

Comment: Could you try an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`? After that, I'm all out of ideas...

Comment: No luck, still the same output. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to use the table tickets, because the results do not filter or aggregate by ticketDate or customerID.  Thus, a shorter sql is

```
SELECT m.moviegenre,
       Sum(d.numoftickets) as SumNum
FROM      details d
LEFT JOIN movies m
  ON d.movieid = m.movieid
GROUP  BY m.moviegenre 
HAVING SumNum > 0
ORDER BY m.moviegenre
```

> added 3/28 am

I am not sure what is meant by Duplicates??  In table = details(ticketId, movieId, numOfTickets) ??
I would expect that ticketId is unique, so what would explain duplicates?
Is the same ticketId being printed twice, repeatedly??

Determine what number of ticketId are duplicates--

```
SELECT ticketId, count(*) as cnt
FROM      details d
GROUP By ticketId
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Determine what number of "details" rows are duplicates--

```
SELECT ticketId, movieId, numOfTickets, count(*) as cnt
FROM      details d
GROUP By ticketId, movieId, numOfTickets
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Then again, it may be that table = movies(movieId, movieGenre, moviePrice) is the one with duplicates??
Determine what number of movieId are duplicates--

```
SELECT movieId, count(*) as cnt
FROM   movies m
GROUP BY movieId
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Remove duplicates from details--

```
SELECT m.moviegenre,
       Sum(d.numoftickets) as SumNum
FROM
   (Select Distinct * From  details) d
LEFT JOIN movies m
  ON d.movieid = m.movieid
GROUP  BY m.moviegenre 
ORDER BY m.moviegenre
```

Comment: it gives me the same output as the query mentioned in the comments of the post, so I'm assuming it takes in account duplicates as well. Not sure if I can use distinct in your query

Comment: I think putting a LEFT JOIN then HAVING sumNumOfTickets > 0 is kind of useless.  You might want to have result with 0 on top of it... so I would remove the HAVING personally.  PS. I slightly edited your query to respect column name and have a more explicit alias, awaiting approval.

Comment: @JapFios Please share with us some of the output from this query, and explain why resultset is not right.
See my additions above.  (I have removed the Having per Michael)